# Trying to see python version returns -bash: /usr/local/bin/python3.7: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pyenv

I was trying (unsuccessfully) to change my python version from 2.7.16 to 3.8.5 using pyenv, and now when I try to see my current python version with `python -V`, I get `-bash: /usr/local/bin/python3.7: No such file or directory`

Comment: You probably just need to set your python to the pyenv version using pyenv global <version> or pyenv local <version>

Comment: still got the same issue!

Comment: ok since you removed probably removed python 2.7 and you did not have python 3.x installed it is looking for your native python which is why you are getting this error 
I would try a couple of things first of all install python outside of pyenv and secondly check that it exists in the path

PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"

also confirm you have 

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi